# Perl. Working with two inputs from a directory

Tags: xml, perl

I'm working with perl. I have a lot of files which are named ????_header.xml (e.g. 0001_header.xml, 0002_header.xml, and so on) and a lot of files named ????_text.xml (e.g. 0001_text.xml, ...). All this files are saved inside a folder called "input".

On the other side, I have a folder called "output". I need to edit some data from the both kind of inputs (header and text) and save the edition in a ".txt" file. But I need one ".txt" file for each pair (header.xml plus text.xml). For instance, I need to read the file 0001_header.xml, do some editions, read the file 0001_text.xml, do some editions, print all editions in a ".txt file" and save it in the output folder. And so on...

In other words, I need to work with two inputs simultaneously and print the result in a different third file.

I tried with this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir IN, 'input';
my @lines1 = grep { /header.xml$/ } readdir IN;
closedir IN;

opendir IN, 'input';
my @lines2 = grep { /text.xml$/ } readdir IN;
closedir IN;

for my $lines1 (@lines1) {
open IN, '<', "input/$lines1" || next;
open OUT, '>', "output/$lines1" || die "can't open file output/$lines1";
while(<IN>) {
#to do several modifications
}
close IN;
}

for my $lines2 (@lines2) {
open IN, '<', "input/$lines2" || next;
open OUT, '>', "output/$lines2" || die "can't open file output/$lines2";
while(<IN>) {
#to do several modifications
print OUT;
}
close OUT;
close IN;
}
```

My problem is that I do not know how to manage my outputs. That is, how to save the modifications from the inputs in a .txt file output. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should make it clearer.

The `input` directory is read, and whenever a header file is found the corresponding text file name is constructed (with the same number). If this also exists then an output file is opened in the `output` directory with the same number as the input files and a `.txt` extension, and the two input file are opened and processed.

Note that all this does is copy the header and the text file contents to the output file. You will want to do more to the data before you `print` it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

opendir my $dh, 'input';

while (my $file = readdir $dh) {
  next unless $file =~ /\A(\d{4})_header.xml\z/;

  my $header_name = $file;
  my $text_name = "$1_text.xml";
  next unless -f "input/$text_name";

  open my $output, '>', "output/$1.txt";

  open my $hdr_in, '<', "input/$header_name";
  while (<$hdr_in>) {
    print $output $_;
  }
  close $hdr_in;

  open my $txt_in, '<', "input/$text_name";
  while (<$txt_in>) {
    print $output $_;
  }
  close $txt_in;

  close $output;

  warn "Output file 'output/$text_name' written\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I think keeps things elegant. Please let me know if I did not fully answer your question.

I put the leading numbers of the filename into a hash as the keys, and put both files into that hash element. This keeps the two related files paired.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = "./"; #or your directory

opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "$!";

my %files;
while(my $file = readdir($dh)){
    if(my ($key) = $file =~ /^(.+?)_(header|text)\.xml$/){
            push @{ $files{$key} }, $file;
    }
}

for my $key (keys %files){
    for(@{ $files{$key} }){
        if(/header\.xml$/) { short_open($_, \&dostuff_header) }
        elsif(/text\.xml$/) { short_open($_, \&dostuff_text) }
    }
}

sub short_open {
    my ($filename, $sub) = @_;
    open my $fh, '<', $dir . $filename or die "$!";
    open my $out, '>', $dir . $filename . "out.xml" or die "$!"; #replace $dir and remove out.xml, I used them for my own testing

    while (my $line = <$fh>){
        print $out $sub->($line);
    } 
}

sub dostuff_text {
    my ($text) = @_;
    #do stuff with text lines
    return $text;
}

sub dostuff_header {
    my ($header) = @_;
    #do stuff with header lines
    return $header;
}
```

Only uses 1 loop to get the input data and 1 loop to do the output data.

I moved the actual work into two functions, so essentially every action that they both do similarly, line `open` is typed only once.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the kinds of operations you are performing on files, however since they are xml, consider reading them in with an xml parser like XML::Fast. That will give you a hash of xml content (or two hashes, one for each file). Then you can perform any kind of operations on both hashes and then combine them and just convert the hash back to xml and print it to a single file.